# To Write Soql Query between Two custom Objects

Tags: soql

Iam trying to write a soql query to fetch child records from parent object
Iam getting an **error** like below.

> Didn't understand relationship 'ObjectB__r' in FROM part of query
>   call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to
>   append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference
>   your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

I wrote query like this

```
List<ObjectA__C> result = [SELECT Id,Name,(SELECT Name,MdField__c from ObjectB__r)From ObjectA__c];
```

- object A is parent
- Object B is child
- `MdField__c` is the field in child object related to parent

could you please help for this

Comment: Double check the child relationship name on the lookup field (child to parent).

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you have to confirm that you are using the correct relationship name in your query. 

**Note** : When you use inner query for retrieve child objects, you have to use the plural form of the object API name.

Best place is to check the correct relationship name is the `WSDL`. Go to ***Setup > Develop > API > Generate Enterprise WSDL***

Open the generated WSDL and check for your `objectA` and under that the relationship name for `objectB` (Something like `<element name="objectBs__r" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>`)

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same error while querying the result for parent-child relationship. this error is because in the case of parent-to-child relationship we have to use the plural of the child object appended with __r. So in that case your query shuld be as given:-
List result = [SELECT Id,Name,(SELECT Name,MdField__c from ObjectBs__r)From ObjectA__c];

For further understanding and help in the case of query's and parent-child relationship you can just go through this link:- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm

Thanks.